# Qt XML Inheritance

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have a baseclass and 3 subclasses who inherit from baseclass.
Now when I save objects of these classes in an XML, I will need the class name because when i load the xml again I need it to be the correct object of course.

How can I do this? I have tried the object->metaObject()->className() but this returns me the name of the baseclass, which I of course am not seeking for?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Q_OBJECT macro for each subclass so it's own metaObject will be generated with proper class name.